# Is it possible to use a command argument with double quotes in a postpublish script?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I want to call a command in a `postpublish` script for my ASP.NET Core project. The command requires an argument that contains spaces and is wrapped in `"`.  Below is the desired command that I would run, this works when running manually from the command line:

`dotnet nswag webapi2swagger /Assembly:./path/to/assembly.dll /Output:./path/to/swagger.json /InfoTitle:"My API Name" /InfoVersion:v1`

In my `project.json` this command is wrapped in a JSON string.  In order to use quotes in the string I escape them with `\`:

`"dotnet nswag webapi2swagger /Assembly:%publish:OutputPath%/assembly.dll /Output:%publish:OutputPath%/docs/swagger.json /InfoTitle:\"My API\" /InfoVersion:v1"`

Unfortunately, while this creates a valid JSON string, the command that runs at post publish appears to actually resolve the escape characters.  As a result the value passed to `InfoTitle` is `\"My` and not `"My API"` like I would expect.

Is this a bug?  Is it possible to somehow escape quotes differently in a `postpublish` script in order to get the results I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem where I needed to run a command on postPublish but got the message "No executable found matching command "cmd.exe"" when publishing within VS2015.

What I ended up doing is to create a postPublish.cmd file in the project root and configuring it to run on postPublish in project.json, passing the publish output folder to the script.

```
    "postpublish": [
        "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%",
        "postPublish.cmd %publish:OutputPath%",
    ]
```

You will have more control inside the postPublish.cmd script and do not need to escape "path"'s, e.g.:

```
:: use %1 to access the temp publish folder:
rmdir /s /q "%1\wwwroot\Uploads"

:: The script will be executed at the root of your project. Testing this:
cd >> test.txt
type "project.json" >> testing2.txt
```